# How to get rid of the write permission on the mounted cifs storage from users?

Tags: mount, cifs

A disk array is mounted by

`sudo mount -t cifs REMOTE_DIR MNT_DIR -o username=admin,password=xxx`

But all the mounted contents are under mode 0777, that means everyone can change and delete the files.

I tried to add `ro` after `-o` to make it read only, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you entering the command correctly? It should be:

```
sudo mount -t cifs REMOTE_DIR MNT_DIR -o ro,username=admin,password=xxx
```

This works fine on Ubuntu 15.04. Although directories show as owner-writable they aren't: it is a cosmetic error.

If you have entered the command correctly, you should get the error "Read-only file system" when you attempt to make changes. If you don't get this, you can work round the problem by creating a second share on the remote system, but make this read-only. That will give you complete protection from changes to the remote file system.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It just looks to be mode 777. I tried mkdir and got an error of "Read-only file system"